# How to deal with JSON response which is in the form of list of JSON's in Locust (Python)

Tags: python, api, post, locust

I get a response (using postman) in the following format when I make a POST request (and I am passing the payload when i make this POST request).

[{"id":22,"name":tom,"age":10}]

Now, when I try resp.json(), I am getting either a JSON decode error or Unable to Parse JSON error. Is there a way to deal with this using the FastHTTPuser library for locust or using the requests library and retrieve the response from the API call as json?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the API you are using to generate that JSON has an error - tom should be under quotes ("tom") as well.

```
import json
json.loads('{"id":22,"name":tom,"age":10}') # fails with JSONDecodeError
json.loads('{"id":22,"name":"tom","age":10}') # works as expected
```